# How to set children position dynamically in WPF

Tags: wpf

we have three control inside stackpannel now i want to change the control position dynamically .
we have searching Google but we don't find any solution.

please solve my problem.

thanx in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you want to freely place these elements, like in a drawing or graph application. Or do you want to reorder elements, like tabs in a browser to change their position in a list?

Answer (score 5):

If you are changing the position of elements inside a container then a StackPanel is the wrong container to use. It's designed to stack (!) elements on top of each other (or along side each other) with a spacing determined by the margins on each element.

If you want to move things around then you'll need a [`Canvas`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx). With this you can then change the position of the elements on the canvas from code.

For example if you have the following:

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle1" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="31"
               Width="63" Height="41" Fill="Blue"  />
    <Ellipse x:Name="El;ipse1" Canvas.Left="130" Canvas.Top="79"
             Width="58" Height="58" Fill="Blue"  />
    <Path x:Name="Path1" Canvas.Left="61" Canvas.Top="28"
          Width="133" Height="98" Fill="Blue" 
          Stretch="Fill" Data="M61,125 L193,28"/>
</Canvas>
```

You can then change the position of elements like this:

```
Rectangle1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 45);
Rectangle1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 60);
```

Comment: but we have three different control like image,list view,slide image which is user control.it is possible to set potion with three different control.

Comment: @jadavsuresh - yes, just replace "Rectangle", "Ellipse" and "Path" with your controls.